Failing to build IOS on codemagic (Flutter)
*NOTE
dont have a mac
i came back to an old project and wanted to publish a new version ( in the past i published multiple apps on codemagic for android and ios and had no problem)
after bumping versions of the firebase packages, i got the following error:

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Compiling for iOS 12.0, but module 'FirebaseAuth' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 13.0:

easy peasy i remember this error, so in my pod file i changed the version to platform :ios, '13.0'
and at the bottom i tried all of the combinations that i found on stack overflow of the post install
something like this:

post_install do |installer|
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
         end
    end
end
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end

but i still got the same error. looked at old apps i made and the podfile looks roughly the same


i would like to avoid downgrading the firebase packages.

flutter version is 3.24.3 ( stable at the moment)

sorry if i missed important info
please save me from apple

You will need to change the minimum deployment target for your project. The simplest way to do this is to open the Xcode project in Xcode.

thanks, is there another way to do it through codemagic/ ios file(podfile)?
i thought the line "platform :ios, '13.0'" at the top of the podfile is responsible for that

No, that sets the version for the pods target. You need to change the version for the Runner target that your project produces. You could try and edit the Xcode xcproject file, but this is risky.

To update minimum deployment target on Xcode from codemagic, try to enable SSH access when building, use RDP tool to access Mac Virtual Machine and try to open Xcode and do it.
